# Как изменить место размещения html файлов в Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

По дефолту в Spring стоит папка `resources/templates`, куда должны помещаться все html-файлы, а я хочу ее изменить на `webapp/WEB-INF/views`.

Как можно это сделать?

Comment: Именно на `webapp/WEB-INF/views` или все-таки на `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views`? И правильно ли я вас понял, что речь про Spring Boot? Вы приложение в JAR или в WAR собираете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте в `application.yml`: `spring.thymeleaf.prefix: /WEB-INF/views`

Comment: Я не очень давно занимаюсь java, можно поподробней куда добавить prefix?

Comment: Создайте файл `application.yml` в каталоге `src/main/resources` и добавьте в него эту строчку. См. также документацию: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.x/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: Огромное спасибо. То, что нужно.

Comment: Хотя не пошло. я создал файл application.yml в каталоге src/main/resources, но все по старому. Может если Вы могли бы посмотреть чего уменя не хватает, вот ссылка на репу https://github.com/ITInstituts/MyNote

Comment: Не хочу так беспардонно врываться в эту идиллию, но почему именно application.yml  и что более интересно почему  spring.thymeleaf.prefix: /WEB-INF/views?

Comment: @barmaglott  А как правильно?

Comment: Да дофига правильных вариантов один из которых сконфигурировать в applicationContext.xml bean с выбранным вами viewResolver где и указать ваш prefix.

Comment: @barmaglott Автор не указал тег `spring-boot`, но я это понял из контекста и поэтому дал такой совет. Параметр `spring.thymeleaf.prefix` это из Spring Boot. В целом, тут сложно дать точный ответ не зная деталей, например, в моем случае файл называется `application-prod.properties`, потому что я не использую YAML конфигурацию и потому что для разных профилей настройки немного отличаются.

Comment: Дык зачем Вы точный ответ даете? У автора и так, судя по его проекту каша в голове, а тут вы со своими советами. И таки да Вы угадали это Spring boot, но как Вы черт подери по вопросу поняли что надо конфигурировать Thymeleaf? Поделитесь опытом сенсей ?;)

Comment: @barmaglott немного каши не помешает =) что конкретно вам не нравится в проэкте? Буду рад любому совету.

Comment: @barmaglott я точно не помню, но разве в Spring Boot не Thymeleaf по-умолчанию используется? (Ну а что делать, если не отвечать? Хочется минусовать конечно и закрывать такие вопросы, чтобы доки шли читали, но тогда я перейду на сторону зла :])

Comment: @Maksims Понимаете...Spring обладает определенной философией ,что ли, и это относится к конфигурированию в том числе. И не понимая что вы хотите сделать(в абстракциях Spring) Вам очень тяжело будет понять как это сделать. Почитайте литературу :).

Comment: @Slava Semushin А Вы типа на стороне света? Что-то написали, человек воткнул, заработало плюс, нет да и фиг с ним.А что он там понял\не понял пофиг:(. Кстати suffix кто определять будет ? Мастер Йода :)?

Comment: @barmaglott думаю, что suffix будет использоваться дефолтный (`.html`) Кстати, я топик стартеру ссылку дал на доку с описанием всех опций, чтобы было от чего отталкиваться, если захочет больше вникнуть.

Comment: @barmaglott Я очень извиняюсь, что вмешиваюсь в вашу высокую дискуссию, о смысле которой мне пока не понять. Но можно я вставлю пару предложений? Я совсем не давно занимаюсь Java, а Spring-ом еще меньше. Спасибо Slava Semushin за предоставленную ссылку на doc она мне пригодится, но не сейчас, т.к. я 90 % там не понял. Если знаете, то не могли бы посоветовать к прочтению или просмотру полезные материалы о Spring? Технология очень интересна и я хотел бы посветить ей побольше времени. Заранее благодарен.
П.С. можно ещё раз объяснить где прописать prefix

Comment: @Maksims Добавьте параметр `spring.thymeleaf.suffix` в тот же файл.

Comment: @ Slava Semushin Я правильно понял в файл application.yml добавить эти две строчки 
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/WEB-INF/views
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html

Comment: Да. Зачем вы добавили `classpath:` в `prefix`?

Comment: @ Slava Semushin так было в примере документации http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html